# Creating an alarm, for five different time in daily basis for iPhone App

Tags: iphone, xcode

How to create an alarm for five different time in daily basis for the year for iPhone App
?
the five different time in daily basis are scheduled

Comment: Are the times different each day?  Here is an idea, have it display a compass showing the way Mecca while your at it.

Comment: Yes, these five time are muslim prayer time. i don't want a compass

Answer (score 0):

Use [local notification](http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2010/04/local-push-notification-sample-code-os.html).

Create 5 different local notification and set the repeat unit as daily

Refer [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I want for time notification for the five different time which are tabulated or saved in excel sheet

Comment: Get the time value and create the UILocalnotifcations for all of them

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the notification.repeatInterval

like following

```
NSInteger index = [scheduleControl selectedSegmentIndex];
     switch (index) {
    case 1:
        notif.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
        break;
    case 2:
        notif.repeatInterval = NSHourCalendarUnit;
        break;
    case 3:
        notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
        break;
    case 4:
        notif.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
        break;
    default:
        notif.repeatInterval = 0;
        break;
}
```

This will help you 
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/9/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html
Thanks,
Naveed